# Classifying text that shows intention do do something in the future using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to classify text that shows intention to do something in the future. For example, "Tonight I will go home and eat dinner", "Tomorrow, I will apply for that job", "I have decided I will have a word with my boss".

It seems the obvious strategy would be to look at text that has future tense. But this wouldn't be a perfect strategy. The following sentences don't show intent but do use future tense "Next month he will be ten years old", "I believe it will be a nice party".

I am looking for some general strategies to go about this problem. If I had a lot of labelled data could I train an algorithm to figure this out? Is there a Stanford library that could do this quite easily?

Many thanks

Comment: Quote from Dr. MIchael Roth: "identifying/classifying intentions has been one of the early and lofty goals of NLP that people have forgotten about over the years.I think it's very interesting but also very difficult
there are some small (and mostly weird) data sets out there
but someone should really work on this as a large-scale long-term project"

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to where you got that quote from?

Comment: Personal communication :)